# What's this called? $\mathbb{C}[d/dx]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory, notation

The 'ring of differential operators wrt x' ?

Thx.

Comment: The ring of *linear* differential operators *with constant coefficients*, rather.

Comment: @MarianoSuarez-Alvarez: Isn't $\mathbb{C}[d/dx]$ only *isomorphic* to the aforementioned ring?

Comment: It depends on what, exactly, the notation means, really.